# Individual User Accounts to No Authentication in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to change Authentication from Individual User Accounts to No Authentication in ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Just Remove the controller and its views and don't put Authorize and Authenticate tags anywhere

Comment: When you select an authentication method, project template adds some nuget packages as well as some code files and configuration entries. I don not know any simple way to remove these things. You may consider removing all those stuff manually or creating a new project with no authentication and move your files to them.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** While creating project click on **Change Authentication**

[image]

**Step 2:** select **No Authentication**

[image]